# Spring - disable path extension truncation / content negotiation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In SpringBoot v2.1.3, when setting up a **@RequestMapping** like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/assets/{name}")
public AssetInfo assetInfo(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
  return getAssetInfo(name);
}
```

a query to `/assets/image123.jpg` would cause:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:219)
```

because it assumes the produced Content-Type *must* be **`image/jpeg`**.

Comment: Just for fun, if you ask an url like `/assets/email@email.com`, Spring will negotiate a content of type *application/x-msdownload*.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable this in a [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) - which will solve the problem of content negotiation - but Spring still excludes the extension from the PathVariable (**`id = "image123"`**). This can be disabled using `setUseSuffixPatternMatch`:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurationForMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Just adding to [the answer from TeNNox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54884180/611526) the missing bits for an easier copy&paste :) I would have added a comment but you cannot write multiline code there.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurationForMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have assimilated your suggestions :P